# not install node_modules when I type this command "npm install"

Tags: node.js, npm-install

when i install node_modules with this command 
`npm install`, I get below errors.
in this case, how can fix this errors?

```
npm ERR! errno HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.7.2.tgz failed, reason: Parse Error

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IR-16\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-25T10_35_26_869Z-debug.log
```

my package.json is following:

```
{
  "name": "discover",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "swiper": "3.4.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

as you can see, never installed `acorn` package.
this error happens when i install ````node modules``` in all projects.

Comment: Can you provide a full log?

Comment: described errors is all.

Comment: Which acorn version you are using, please add your package.json

Comment: then try running `npm install acorn --unsafe-perm` and let us know what is says.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `"acorn": "^5.7.2",` from `package.json` related acorn and follow the following steps,

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Then install acorn manually via terminal

```
npm install acorn --save
```

If it will not work then you can try with

```
npm install acorn --unsafe-perm --save
```

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: never installed ```acorn``` in my package.json

Comment: Can you please share your package.json?

Comment: just added the package.json.